# Expand ext4 partition in the beginning

Tags: linux, partitioning

Many posts on superuser explain how to expand a ext partition: Remove the partition entry and create a new partition entry with a larger partition end.

However, the partition I need to expand is located in the end of the drive with free space before it, so I would need to set a smaller partition start - but I am not sure how to do that without potentially destroying the partition.

How can I expand a partition like this (preferrably using gparted or similar linux-based tools).

Answer (score 0):

Make a backup, because these things tend to fail at the worst times.

Then just use gparted as you normally would.  You'll likely want to use a livecd/livedvd, and make sure that the partition(s) affected are unmounted.

In gparted, select the partition you want to resize, then right-click and select "resize/move".  In the new window, grab the handles and adjust the partition accordingly.

If you need to shrink another partition to make room for the one you're enlarging, do that first, and if it's a Windows partition, be sure to use the Windows tools to check the integrity of the resize operation.

Note that if this partition contains /boot, you'll have to reinstall the Grub boot loader, otherwise it will fail when it tries to read the partition's previous start sector.